# How does Visual Studio IDE compile C++ code using just a button?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, command-line-interface

I have seen how David J. Malan has used *command line interface* to compile C code into machine-executable code. I think C++ works the same way. I have a question that I haven't found any source that mentions. How does Visual Studio IDE compile C++ code using just a button *Start Debugging*. Does the button generate some commands on the CLI to compile C++ code underneath the hood?

Comment: It triggers MSBuild to compile your project if not already compiled. There is also a build button in the IDE. That it is what an IDE is all about. Writing source code, compiling and debugging (and more) in one application

Comment: The answer is more or less "yes". The "Start Debugging" button compiles the code if necessary, and then executes it with the debugger. And yes it's exactly the sdame for C and C++

Comment: All the options/definitions needed by the compiler in VS are inside the project file; this makes the magic

Answer (score 2):

Most IDEs do this, generate command lines (or equivalent structures) and call the appropriate programs. Some IDEs have built-in compilers, though. Visual Studio uses CLI programs under the hood.

Many applications with a GUI work this way, especially on non-Windows systems.